# Async Storage in react native expo managed workflow

Tags: asynchronous, expo, storage, workflow, managed

How can I store async Storage data even after clearing app data or storage without using auth or server code please help in react native expo managed workflow

Please help me please help me
Sorry but I can't provide code if u can help please reply